# How to call EnumAdapters from IDXGFactory in c?

Tags: c, dxgi

How to call the `EnumAdapters` function in c from `IDXGFactory`

```
    UINT i = 0; 
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory = NULL;
    IDXGIAdapter * pAdapter; 
    HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory(&IID_IDXGIFactory, (void**)(&pFactory) );

    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to create DXIFactory object\n");
    }
```

using `pFactory->EnumAdapters(i, pAdapter)` does not work and causes this error

```
struct "IDXGIFactory" has no field "EnumAdapters"
```

Comment: What about `IDXGIFactory_EnumAdapters(pFactory, i, pAdapter)`

Comment: @RomanR. where is the documentation for that

Comment: It exists somewhere probably, however you might find what you look for just looking for "using COM interfaces in plain C".

Comment: @RomanR. is there a header file that i have to add or do i need to link something other than `dxgi`

Comment: The header is `dxgi.h` as [documented on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory-enumadapters#requirements), the library `dxgi.lib` to link is also mentioned there.

Comment: @RomanR. i did link `dxgi.lib` and added the header `dxgi.h` but i get this `implicit declaration of function 'IDXGIFactory_EnumAdapters'` and it does not compile moreover a quick google dork returns 103 results with no mention of the function you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in reading up on topic "using COM in plain C", where you can find relevant detailed explanations.

For you very specific question the code might look like:

```
#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

int main()
{
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory = NULL;
    UINT i = 0; 
    IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter; 
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CreateDXGIFactory(&IID_IDXGIFactory, (void**)(&pFactory));
    hr = pFactory->lpVtbl->EnumAdapters(pFactory, i, &pAdapter);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, another way is to take advantage of `COBJMACROS` in which case you have `IDXGIFactory_EnumAdapters` available to you.

```
#define COBJMACROS

#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

int main()
{
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory = NULL;
    UINT i = 0; 
    IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter; 
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CreateDXGIFactory(&IID_IDXGIFactory, (void**)(&pFactory));
    hr = IDXGIFactory_EnumAdapters(pFactory, i, &pAdapter);
    return 0;
}
```